# Group Chat Solutions With AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, chat, real-time

**EDIT: The original question asked for a real-time solution. I am not sure this is necessary. It should be about as fast as sending a standard SMS text message.**

I want to integrate group chat in my android / ios app. There is a similar question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16450223/ideas-for-scaling-chat-in-aws), but the answers are old and I would like to see if there are any new / better solutions.

I am currently using multiple AWS services in my app, and would like to keep my chat solution in the same ecosystem. However, if there is a solution outside of AWS that is much easier to implement with good results, I am open to the suggestion.

Based on my research I have come across a couple of possibilties:

- [This AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-build-a-chat-application-with-amazon-elasticache-for-redis/) lightly covers using ElastiCache for this purpose
- [This LinkedIn slideshow](https://www.slideshare.net/akitsukada/realtime-chat-backend-on-aws-iot-20160422) demonstrates the possibility of using AWS IoT

Requirements for my chat:

- Would like to be able to support up to 500 people per chat group
- Usable from the web via online portal that has the same general functionality as the mobile app
- Needs to be scalable to handle thousands of groups
- Needs to handle emojies (cross platform)
- Needs to allow for file transfers. Images and GIFs at the very least.
- Send push notifications to users who have elected to recieve them when they are not currently active in the group

Are either of my possiblities a good fit for my requirements? Which would be the easiest to implement? Are there other, easier solutions inside of AWS? Outside of AWS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting this answer to close the question. I ended up switching from AWS to Google Firebase in order to use the Real Time Database.

There is a chat example [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-firebase-chat/#0) that might help anyone that stumbles onto this question.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/tinode/chat

It's not a 100% what you want but close. There is a third-party DynamoDB adapter for it: https://github.com/riandyrn/chat